# Map does not zoom in

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am creating a google maps application using android studio with a login system. The issue I have is that the map does not zoom in. I have only added a simple search bar to the map. When I run the same code on an application without the login system it works perfectly, however, with the login system it does not. So my question is, judging from the code below what could be the reason?

**My app level build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mongodb.stitch.examples.mongorestaurant"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.1'
compile 'org.mongodb:stitch:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


 repositories {

// TODO: Remove once BSON 3.5.0 is released
maven {
    url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
}
}
```

**My MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
PlaceAutocompleteFragment placeAutoComplete;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    placeAutoComplete = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete);
    placeAutoComplete.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

            Log.d("Maps", "Place selected: " + place.getName());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place.getLatLng())
                    .title("Marker in Sydney"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place.getLatLng()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            Log.d("Maps", "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

}

}
```

**My activity_maps.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapsActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
    />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**And my AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mongodb.stitch.examples.mongorestaurant">

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MapsActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I will be grateful for any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to give us more information, e.g. the place in the code where you suspect the problem is.  The map doesn't zoom, but does it even load properly?  In other words, is the zooming really the problem and not something more major than this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , Yes, you are right, when I run the app on another map a big chunk of the map does not even load. I suspect it is because of my login system or the version of the play services which I've put to 10.2.1. Could the issue be because of the poor programming in my login system which affects the map? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the camera focus that would help to auto zoom of your latitude and longitude address , make this logic:

add this line in My MapsActivity class where you add the marker on map :

```
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place.getLatLng(),12);
                    googleMap.moveCamera(cu);
```

this would help you , its help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

private LatLngBounds AUSTRALIA = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(-44, 113), new LatLng(-10, 154));
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(AUSTRALIA, 13));// 13 number is zoom parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,
Add below line inside @Override onMapReady method ,

```
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to zoom in map after getting latitude and longitude, you have to change this line.

from

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place.getLatLng()));
```

to

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place.getLatLng()), 13);
```

here 13 in the above method is zoom level of map, you can change this zoom level according to your application requirement.

and If you want to display zoom controls on google map

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}
```